# Rails Routes, unexpected results (need posts route, not get route)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two paths..

```
checkout GET    /checkout/:product_id(.:format)   checkout#new                                           
         POST   /checkout(.:format)               checkout#create
```

I would like to have `checkout_path` for the post command, but for some reason, if I use `checkout_path()`, it always returns the get path.

```
/checkout/some_id
vs
/checkout


  get  "welcome"                               => "checkout#show"
  get  "checkout/:product_id"                  => "checkout#new", :as => :checkout
  post "checkout"                              => "checkout#create"
```

Comment: Please post corresponding `routes.rb` code

Comment: @Vasfed, posted above

Answer (score 0):

`checkout_path` helper comes from your `:as => :checkout`, so:

```rb
  get  "welcome"              => "checkout#show"
  get  "checkout/:product_id" => "checkout#new",    as: :some_other_name
  post "checkout"             => "checkout#create", as: :checkout
```